# Python how to handle # in a dictionary

Tags: python, json, api

I've got some json from last.fm's api which I've serialised into a dictionary using simplejson. A quick example of the basic structure is below.

```
{
  "artist": "similar": {
    "artist": {
      "name": "Blah",
      "image": [{
        "#text": "URLHERE",
        "size": "small"
      }, {
        "#text": "URLHERE",
        "size": "medium"
      }, {
        "#text": "URLHERE",
        "size": "large"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas how I can access the image urls of various different sizes?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: You should probably paste some of your python code or clarify a bit more.  Looking up a string key in a dictionary that contains "#" works just fine: >>> x = {"#foo":"bar"}          >>> x["#foo"]
'bar'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python does not have any problem with # in strings used as dict keys.

```
>>> import json
>>> j = '{"#foo": 6}'
>>> print json.loads(j)
{u'#foo': 6}
>>> print json.loads(j)[u'#foo']
6
>>> print json.loads(j)['#foo']
6
```

There are, however, problems with the JSON you post. For one, it isn't valid (perhaps you're missing a couple commas?). For two, you have a JSON object with the same key "image" three times, which cannot coexist and do anything useful.

Comment: Ah, your right about the JSON being wrong. I've fixed it now, any ideas how to access the url depending on the size I want?

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, these two syntaxes are equivalent:

```
o.foo
o['foo']
```

In Python they are not.  The first gives you the foo attribute, the second gives you the foo key.  (It's debatable whether this was a good idea or not.)  In Python, you wouldn't be able to access `#text` as:

```
o.#text
```

because the hash will start a comment, and you'll have a syntax error.

But you want

```
o['#text']
```

in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want from the image list with a list comprehension.  Something like

```
desired = [x for x in images if minSize < x['size'] < maxSize]
```

Here, images would be the list of dicts from the inner level of you data structure.